# Подскажите пожалуйста, какое и надо написать условие или как , чтобы можно было сопоставить данные с null в postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть таблицы и результат ----> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=60c3f591e71afeb7e380660273affb24

Мне надо данные из таблицы personal_vlaues добавить в accounts, например если есть tariff у redirect то он изменит ток у этого клиента(redirect) и тариф(tariff), если в это таблице будут модель(model) и (rated_energy) у клиент(redirect) то он изменит у него. Но там есть null и если там стоит null то он оставляет данные те которые уже есть в таблице accounts. А то если так оставить то вместо старых значений поставит null. Null значит ничего. И еще условие, если в будущем я захотел изменить в personal_vlaues или удалить там данные то он сопоставлять данные с этого числа( чтобы не создавать для этого доп. таблицу). Пример: 1 числа были одни значения и потом 3 числа решил изменить, и чтобы он не изменил 1 и 2 число а изменил начиная с 3 числа. Тип проверка по дате. Если надо более подробно что-то уточнить, пишите в коментах.

Comment: Вот блин понять, что тут написано, у меня не получается. Какой-то прям поток сознания. Успокойтесь и перепишите, пожалуйста... заодно объясните, почему вопрос - с тегом PostgreSQL, а fiddle для SQL Server.

Comment: А вообще - просто JOIN и COALESCE.

Comment: @Akina fiddle просто пример как выглядит таблицы и использую PostgreSQL

Comment: Ну так переделайте fiddle под свою СУБД и версию. Вот напишу я запрос для SQL Server, который будет работать на fiddle, но не примется Постгрессом - оно сильно поможет?

Comment: Переделал, я думал то что sql запрос он то одинаковый и можно понять принцип, но потом понял то что у всех бд есть свои плешки и параметры

Answer (score 0):

Если подгонять запрос под требуемый результат, то вот так:

```sql
UPDATE accounts
SET rated_energy = COALESCE(personal_vlaues.rated_energy, accounts.rated_energy),
    tariff = COALESCE(personal_vlaues.tariff, accounts.tariff)
FROM personal_vlaues 
WHERE accounts.object = personal_vlaues.object
  AND accounts.redirect = personal_vlaues.redirect
  AND accounts.model = COALESCE(personal_vlaues.model, accounts.model);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=91f9dfd5c5bf541967357a8c4ad36b26

Но задачу я так и не понял...

Comment: Я вас понял, но к сожалению она не работает с моими данными просто update 0. Я не знаю как можно подробнее объяснить